# missing required architecture armv7 in file? Ask

Tags: objective-c, architecture, ipa

I keep getting this warning and errors can anyone help?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UTEModelDevices", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ConnectedViewControl.o
"_kUTEQueryRunData", referenced from:
  -[DBXFeedTableViewController syncSucess:] in 
DBXFeedTableViewController.o
"_kUTEQueryHRMData", referenced from:
  -[DBXFeedTableViewController uteManagerDevicesSate:error:userInfo:] 
in DBXFeedTableViewController.o
  -[DBXFeedTableViewController syncSucess:] in 
DBXFeedTableViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UTESmartBandClient", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in DBXFeedTableViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in ConnectedViewControl.o
"_kUTEQueryBloodData", referenced from:
  -[DBXFeedTableViewController uteManagerDevicesSate:error:userInfo:] 
in DBXFeedTableViewController.o
  -[DBXFeedTableViewController syncSucess:] in 
DBXFeedTableViewController.o
 "_kUTEPasswordState", referenced from:
  -[DBXFeedTableViewController uteManagerDevicesSate:error:userInfo:] 
 in DBXFeedTableViewController.o
 "_kUTEQuerySleepData", referenced from:
  -[DBXFeedTableViewController syncSucess:] in 
DBXFeedTableViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UTEModelAlarm", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in DBXFeedTableViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

My app workings fine in the Simulator and Iphone but I don't get archive file.

Answer (score 0):

These errors say that the classes like `UTEModelDevices`, `UTESmartBandClient`, `UTEModelAlarm`, and some other things are not found during linking time of the app binary.

It indicates that it is probably found during compile time, so I feel that you use some framework or a static library which has those "UTE" classes.

So you say that this library works on simulator and iPhone, but doesn't work on "Archive" action.

Usually the difference between a normal device/simulator build for development, and an Archive build is that the development build is made with DEBUG configuration, and Archive build is RELEASE.

Is it possible that your library in project settings is included only for DEBUG configuration, but not included in RELEASE?